# Button and calculating in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

now this is my problem. 
I have 2 views which on both you will calculate something.
I use the same code on both views (but with the small changes so they do not calculate the same thing)
But the problem is, the button on page 2 do NOT calculate anything.
Here is the code for the java file view #2:

> > ```
> > package tk.iWeld.iweld;
> > ```
> >
> > import android.os.Bundle; import android.app.Activity;
> >
> > import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager; import android.view.View;
> >
> > import android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.TextView;
> >
> > public class TestLay extends Activity {
> >
> > ```
> >     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
> >
> >     @Override
> >     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> >         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
> >         setContentView(R.layout.testlayout);
> >
> >     }
> >
> >     public void StartClickListener(View view) {
> >
> >     }
> >
> >     public void calculateClickListener(View view) {
> >      // make sure we handle the click of the calculator button
> >
> >      if (view.getId() == R.id.button) {
> >       // get the references to the widgets
> >       EditText text1Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
> >       EditText text2Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
> >       TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultat);
> >
> >
> >
> >       float text1 = Float.parseFloat(text1Text.getText().toString());
> >       float text2 = Float.parseFloat(text2Text.getText().toString());   
> >       // calculate the result value
> >
> >       float totalresult = calculateRESULT(text1, text2);
> >
> >
> >       // now set the value in the result text
> >
> >       resultText.setText("Debug=ok" +  (totalresult));
> >      }
> >     }
> >
> >     // the formula to calculate the result index
> >
> >     private float calculateRESULT (float text1, float text2) {
> >
> >      return (float) (3.14 * (text1 * text1) * text2 / 4 / 1000000);
> >     }   }
> > ```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to diagnose a problem like this is to break it down.

1) Check that you're getting inside your click listener:

```
if (view.getId() == R.id.button) {
   //make sure you get here
}
```

2) If you're getting inside the click listener OK, simplify your calculateRESULT() function and return a simple result:

```
private float calculateRESULT (float text1, float text2) {

     return 3.14;
}
```

This will help you find where the problem is.

P.S.: I would also suggest you do validation around your inputs:

```
float text1 = 0;
float text2 = 0;
try {
    text1 = Float.parseFloat(text1Text.getText().toString());
    text2 = Float.parseFloat(text2Text.getText().toString());
}
catch(Exception e) {
    // handle if user inputs non-number
}
```

Comment: It seems that I do not get into the button thingy, because I added this:

Comment: TextView resu = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
resu.setText("Debug=ok");
And it didnt change... But why does it work on page1 then?

Comment: Check if your calculateClickListener() is getting called at all. Put a log statement before if (view.getId() == R.id.button). And check what view.getId() is.

Comment: What kind of errors? Post the errors and the code, so I can see what you're doing

Comment: Either your calculateClickListener() doesn't get called, or it gets called with the wrong button id. Check how you call the calculateClickListener, I bet that's where your issue is.

Comment: Nevermind, what do you mean check what view.getID() is, how do I check that?

Comment: You can see the code above so If you cant see it, I probably cannot too. (Cant tag Eduard)

Comment: You should put a breakpoint inside your calculateClickListener() and step through it. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html#tools